# How to to check if a column contains words regardless of their order

Tags: sql, postgresql

#### Table design

- Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE letters(
  id serial2 primary key,
  letterset text
);
```

- Insert data

```sql
INSERT INTO letters(letterset) 
VALUES
('A'),
('A B'),
('A B C'),
('B'),
('B C'),
('A C'),
('C B'),
('C W A');
```

- My solution to finding any order of letters

```sql
SELECT * FROM letters
WHERE letterset ~~* '%a%' AND letterset ~~* '%C%';
```

#### Question

is there a better way to do this in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that this would be faster but it remains the same for any number of search letters. First convert `letterset` and the letters to search for into arrays and then check if the first [contains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) the second.

```sql
select * from letters 
where string_to_array(upper(letterset), ' ') @> string_to_array('C,A', ',');
```

Comment: I want case insensitivity that's why I used ILIKE `~~*`

Comment: That's why I use `upper`